# Machine Learning models and "rare-event" independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I have a data set which tries to predict a continuous variable, say house prices $Y$. My independent variables consits of things such as, square meters, number of bedrooms, bathrooms etc. However, I also have a rare event variable such as "Has a famous person previously lived in the house" (I cannot think of any other examples), the point is that the variable has a very low number of occurrences and appears on only a few houses and is a categorical variable "yes" / "no". Assuming the rare event variable has a positive impact on the prediction of house prices, i.e. houses which previously belonged to a famous person is X% higher than other houses in the area.

How does XGBoost, randomForest, LightGBM etc. manage such rare events in the independent variables? I have read a lot about the predictions of rare events in the dependent variables such as fraud detection etc. but I cannot find any papers or material which discuss how to measure the impact of rare-event variables. Are there any papers which study the effects that rare-event variables have on the model?

Data:

```
price     mtrs_sqrd, bedrooms, bathrooms, famous_person
100,000     100         5          2            0
123,000      80         6          3            0
 80,000      90         3          1            0
150,000     120         6          3            0
110,000      80         2          2            0
170,000     130         5          2            0 # house is the same as below
200,000     130         5          2            1 # but famous person lived here and has a higher price, thus the marginal contribution of this variable when it is a "1" is higher than when it is a "0".
117,000     110         4          3            0
135,000     115         4          2            0
127,000     120         4          3            0
 90,000     100         3          1            0
```

I am looking for any resourses which focus on these type of rare-event variables.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the rare event variables will lead to very high uncertainty around their coefficients unless their effect is huge. They lead to collinearity issues too. Consider their correlation with the constant term (intercept). If your data set is very large, the rare occurences of non zero in your rare event variable will be averaged out, and Pearson correlation will be close to 1 between the variable and the intercept. This can mess up both of them.

Conceptually, there's very little data to estimate the coefficients of these variables. The sample size effectively shrinks to the number of non-zero occurrences of the variable in the data set, then you have the impact of all other variables, so you end up with high number of variables to estimate on a very small effective data set.

In some MSAs, like Beverly Hills or Comptons, the famous person is in every other house.